# How do I find out which one of those pesky programs keeps waking my machine from sleep?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

Every night I put my Windows 7 machine into sleep mode, and every morning I wake up and the thing is running.

How I can find out which process is waking the thing up?

I've already looked at the Event Log and for the past two days the answer seems to be the "Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) service entered the running state."

What can I do about this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have scanner attached to your computer and ever night your cat jumps on the scanner pressing the "scan" button ;)

Comment: Does powercfg -energy find anything?  This sounds more like it might be a scheduled task or something, though.

Comment: @ChrisF catscan? ^^

Comment: did you check the task sheduler? could also be a piece of hardware, e.g. the network card. you can disable the "wake up" feature of devices in the devide manager

Comment: I remember my sister's laptop having a similar problem. I think I disabled the BIOS' "Wake on LAN" feature, and that solved it. Might be worth trying.

Comment: @Shinrai The result of the powercfg -energy command says "The Power Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) could not be loaded."

Comment: @ChrisF :) I don't have a cat.  I do have scanner, but it's not attached and hasn't been for years.  Unless there's some sort of "ghost driver" that I don't know about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate has this built in!

I went to `Control Panel -> View By: Category -> System and Security -> View Performance Information`, and at the top on the right programs are listed that might be interrupting sleep mode.

After shutting off the programs listed, my computer no longer wakes up from sleep mode.

Comment: This option does not exist.

Comment: yes, I don't see such an option either...

Answer (score 3):

An excellent overview about this topic can be found at http://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/, specifically

```
powercfg -lastwake 
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed 
powercfg -waketimers
```

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.blackviper.com/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition_(WIA)) is a useful link regarding it's dependencies:

> Dependencies
>
> What service Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) needs to function properly:
>   
>  Remote Procedure Call (RPC) (S, HB, HP, P, U, E)
>   
>  DCOM Server Process Launcher (S, HB, HP, P, U, E)
>   
>  RPC Endpoint Mapper (S, HB, HP, P, U, E) 
>   
>  Shell Hardware Detection (S, HB, HP, P, U, E)
>   
>  Remote Procedure Call (RPC) (S, HB, HP, P, U, E)
>   
>  DCOM Server Process Launcher (S, HB, HP, P, U, E) 
>   
>  RPC Endpoint Mapper (S, HB, HP, P, U, E)
>
> What other service require Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) to function
>   properly:  None (S, HB, HP, P, U, E)

Which doesn't really help diagnose what's causing it, but at least shows nothing else should be calling it (ie no dependencies).

There are several security vulnerabilites which Microsoft have patched with it, so make sure you've got all security updates... Failing that i would be inclined to stop the service one night and see if it has restarted itself before the morning then check/change it's startup properties (mine is running here and set to automatic by default).  Then again i like breaking things lol ;)

Answer (score 1):

The event log isn't necessarily reliable to determine what woke up the computer. When the computer wakes up, many things may start running, resulting in entries in the log. If you are having difficulties with keeping it sleeping, it may be a good idea to check a couple things:

First, I found that if I have files being shared over the network, sometimes it may cause the computer to wake seemingly randomly. You need to check your sleep settings under advanced power options. Under the advanced settings tree, check the "When Sharing Media" entry, and make sure it is set to "Allow the computer to sleep". "Away mode" is a semi-sleep mode that still allows access to shared files and resources. Also go through the other settings and make sure that things aren't allowed to wake the computer up.

If that isn't helpful, also run `powercfg /requests` in a command shell running as an administrator. If there are things that are preventing the computer from remaining in sleep mode, this will reveal them. Even simple, seemingly innocuous things can do this. I found that leaving the Line In audio jack set to enable "listening" (so I can play my Xbox through the computer speakers) prevents the computer from entering sleep mode.