# Laptop turned on from sleep automatically

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep

I found my laptop powered on from Stand by mode about 6 hours later. I did a research around the site to find out the reason why it would automatically turn on from sleep. So, it told me to go into the power management of the devices and disable the wake up of computer sleep. I'll do that.

What I want to know is: Can I know exactly what made my computer wake up from sleep? Does it keep track of it the logs or events?

**Update**:

I have looked into the Event viewer to figure out the time when my computer came out from sleep:

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2013‎-‎09‎-‎10T11:46:31.927985300Z
Wake Time: ‎2013‎-‎09‎-‎10T16:46:38.116075100Z

Wake Source: Unknown
```

It clearly says that the Source was Unknown. Is there still possibility I might get to know?

Comment: Windows Event Viewer (search for "View Event Logs" in your Start screen) will have some clues . . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which one of those pesky programs keeps waking my machine from sleep?](http://superuser.com/questions/353225/how-do-i-find-out-which-one-of-those-pesky-programs-keeps-waking-my-machine-from) also see [Help me find the offending process waking my Windows 7 PC from hibernate every night](http://superuser.com/questions/103380/help-me-find-the-offending-process-waking-my-windows-7-pc-from-hibernate-every-n)