# Laptop turns on immediatelly

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, sleep, hibernate

My Dell XPS 15 with Windows 10 turns on immediately after turning off.

The same with Sleep or Hibernate.

I googled the issue and found following suggestions:
- disable wake events in Bios 
- Disable wake for usb devices (unfortunately, my mouse do not have Power options tab)

So far I have no idea what cause wake, event log entry is not helpful:

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2017‎-‎03‎-‎27T20:53:24.368136500Z
Wake Time: ‎2017‎-‎03‎-‎27T20:53:59.366750800Z

Wake Source: Unknown
```

Here there are suggestion to locate program for windows 7 but this do not work for windows 10 Pro: [How do I find out which one of those pesky programs keeps waking my machine from sleep?](https://superuser.com/questions/353225/how-do-i-find-out-which-one-of-those-pesky-programs-keeps-waking-my-machine-from)

Comment: Are you able to remove the battery on this model? If so does the same issue occur whist plugged in to the mains?

Comment: I had this issue with my desktop. I also found no helpful solutions, so through trial and error of my own, I found that it was due to booting Windows through GRUB. Do you have a Linux partition on your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I did following changes into BIOS to get it fixed (not sure which one actually helped):

- Enabled Wake on power
- Enabled Wake on USB/USB-C
- Enabled Wake on wifi/LAN
- DISABLED additional CPU power mode S3